# Find the url of uploaded blob to firebase storage using python and the _get_download_url() method

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

Like the question says, I would like to understand better how this method works.

The main problem I am facing is the Client param, since all other methods already use my firebase configurations I`m not familiar with the google cloud requirements (client: ~google.cloud.storage.client.Client).

My understanding was that the firebase_admin module was already wrapping the google cloud functionality. Am I understanding something wrong or is this method just not up to date?

The relevant code:

```
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, storageBucket)
bucket = storage.bucket()

blob = bucket.blob(blobName)
blob.upload_from_filename(filename)

blob_url = blob._get_download_url() # This is the part I`m not understanding
```

ps: I know there is a workaround by making the urls public and using those, but I would prefer to solve this a different way if possible.